# Understanding this proof about linearity of expectation

Tags: statistics, random-variables, intuition, expected-value, descriptive-statistics

I'm studying introductory statistis and I'm having a difficult time understanding linearity of expectation. I found this proof from the website Brilliant:

> We'll explicitly prove this theorem for discrete random variables.  By
>   the basic definition of expected value,
>
> \begin{align*} E[X+Y] &= \sum_{x}\sum_{y} \big[(x+y)\cdot
>  P(X=x,Y=y)\big] \\ &=\sum_{x}\sum_{y} \big[x\cdot P(X=x,Y=y)\big]  +
>  \sum_{x}\sum_{y} \big[y\cdot P(X=x,Y=y)\big] \\
>  &=\sum_{x}x\underbrace{\sum_{y} P(X=x,Y=y)}_{P(X=x)}  +
>  \sum_{y}y\underbrace{\sum_{x} P(X=x,Y=y)}_{P(Y=y)} \\ &=\sum_{x}x\cdot
>  P(X=x)  + \sum_{y}y \cdot P(Y=y) \\ &=E[X] + E[Y]. \end{align*}
>
> This result can be extended for (n) variables using induction.
>
> Note that we have never used any properties of independence in this
>   proof, and thus linearity of expectation holds for all random
>   variables!

I'm having a difficult time understanding the proof, can someone help me understand it?

Comment: How far can you get?  What's the first thing you don't understand?

Comment: One way to approach it is that the integral of a sum is the sum of the integrals.

Comment: The proof actually seems very well explained. No one can help if you don't say exactly where you got stuck. If you couldn't understand anything *at all*, I suggest backtracking and reading some definitions again.

Comment: I'm having trouble in the first line. What does P(X  = x, Y = y) mean?

Comment: it is a joint probability density of $X$ and $Y$

Comment: $P(X=x,Y=y)$ is the joint probability that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ take the values $x$ and $y$ simultaneously.